# using for loop for data cleaning

Tags: r

I'm restructuring variables containing blood pressure readings. Each reading contains the systolic and diastolic value separated by a forward slash (/). For this example, there are three readings per row (i.e, per person).

The output I want is to have separate variables for the systolic and diastolic values for each reading.

Here is the data example as csv:

```
id,v1,v2,v3  
1,116 / 77,121 / 68,105 / 76  
2,164 / 67,171 / 79,155 / 68  
3,146 / 109,,  
4,120 / 80,102 / 64,137 / 87   
5,112 / 50,130 / 40,
```

After loading tidyverse, I'm able to do this using separate, for each reading, e.g.,

```r
blPr <- read_csv('BlPr.csv')  
blPr <- blPr %>% separate (v1 , c('v1_sys' , 'v1_dias') , sep = '/' , remove = FALSE)
```

However, since the actual dataset has several more readings per person, I'm seeking to eliminate multiple lines by using a for loop. After reviewing some examples on the web, I tried:

```r
for (i in 1:3) {  
  blPr <- blPr %>% separate (v[i] , c('v[i]_sys' , 'v[i]_dias') , sep = '/' ,   remove = FALSE)  
}
```

It returned the error message:

> ```
> Error in eval_tidy(enquo(var), var_env) : object 'v' not found
> ```

I've modified the code in several ways, but since I'm not understanding what is wrong I'm coming up empty.

Comment: Hi @David, what is the expected output for your example?

Comment: strange: the elements of the header are separated by `,` and the parts of the data by `/`

Comment: I want to have separate variables for the systolic and diastolic readings, that are now separated by a slash in a single variable. All variables are separated by commas in the csv file.

Comment: Hi @David, welcome to StackOverflow!  Can you do ```dput(head(df))``` (where ```df``` is the name of your dataframe) and add that to your question using the ```edit``` option at the bottom left of your question? If you can do that and add your expected output that will help get a faster and relevant answer.

Comment: Which readings would you like to keep per ID? The first, the last, all of them?

Comment: All of them are relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see someone's answer just got accepted, but gonna post mine anyways. If one were to change your code in a minimal possible way, here's a way to go:

```r
for (i in 1:3) {
  blPr <- blPr %>% 
    separate(paste0('v', i), c(paste0('v', i, '_sys'), paste0('v', i, '_dias')), sep = ' / ', remove = F)
}
```

Short explanation to (hopefully) help you understand why your code did not work:
you can use unquoted variable (i.e. column) names as tidyverse arguments but these are not referentially transparent. This means that your code is looking for a column *literally* named `v` inside `blPr` and is obviously not finding one. Sometimes, though as far as I know not always, tidyverse verbs (e.g. `separate`) accept strings with column names to mean those columns -- the feature I used in the above code (notice that `'v'` is a string). For more info, you could read up on tidy evaluation, quasi-quotation and the like.

Comment: This code is much clearer to me and thanks also for your explanation--makes a lot of sense to me. For others who may consult this I've voted this the correct answer. My apologies for any awkwardness--I'm new to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

This code below works ...

```
# Create dataframe
blPr = read.table(text = '
id,v1,v2,v3  
1,116 / 77,121 / 68,105 / 76  
2,164 / 67,171 / 79,155 / 68  
3,146 / 109,,
4,120 / 80,102 / 64,137 / 87   
5,112 / 50,130 / 40,
', header = T, sep = ",")

library(tidyr)

for (i in c(1:3)){
eval(parse(text=paste0(  
"blPr <- blPr %>% separate (v",i," , c('v",i,"_sys' , 'v",i,"_dias') , sep = '/' , remove = FALSE)"
)))
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the code worked perfectly and got the result I was looking for. I'll have some work to do to take the code apart and understand it better. It will help to have this example.

Comment: Great, I'm glad it worked.  Can you mark it as 'correct'?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to keep all readings and put the data into a tidy fomat:

```
result <- data %>%
    gather("reading", "value", -id) %>%
    mutate(value = trimws(value),
           value = ifelse(value == "", NA_character_, value)) %>%
    arrange(id, reading) %>%
    separate(value, c("systolic", "diastolic"), "/", convert = TRUE)


> head(result)
   id reading systolic diastolic
1   1      v1      116        77
2   1      v2      121        68
3   1      v3      105        76
4   2      v1      164        67
5   2      v2      171        79
6   2      v3      155        68
```

You could go further and a) remove NA's and b) put it into long form:

```
result_long <- result %>%
    filter(complete.cases(.)) %>%
    gather("reading_type", "value", -id, -reading) %>% 


> head(result_long)
   id reading reading_type value
1   1      v1     systolic   116
2   1      v2     systolic   121
3   1      v3     systolic   105
4   2      v1     systolic   164
5   2      v2     systolic   171
6   2      v3     systolic   155
```

Tidy formats make it really easy to wrangle and plot data. It is also very easy to put them back into human-readable form. The format chosen in `result` is maybe a good compromise between human-readable and easy to handle.

#### Plotting

```
library(ggplot)

ggplot(result_long) + 
    geom_point(aes(reading, value, color = reading_type, group = reading_type)) +
    geom_line(aes(reading, value, color = reading_type, group = reading_type)) +
    facet_wrap(id ~ .)
```

[image: 1]

#### Putting data into wide form

```
result_wide <- result_long %>% 
    spread("reading_type", "value", drop = TRUE) %>%
    unite("value", c("systolic", "diastolic"), sep = " / ") %>%
    spread("reading", "value")


> result_wide
  id        v1       v2       v3
1  1  116 / 77 121 / 68 105 / 76
2  2  164 / 67 171 / 79 155 / 68
3  3 146 / 109     <NA>     <NA>
4  4  120 / 80 102 / 64 137 / 87
5  5  112 / 50 130 / 40     <NA>
```

#### Data

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- read.table(text = '
id,v1,v2,v3  
1,116 / 77,121 / 68,105 / 76  
2,164 / 67,171 / 79,155 / 68  
3,146 / 109,,
4,120 / 80,102 / 64,137 / 87   
5,112 / 50,130 / 40,
', header = T, sep = ",")
```

Comment: I see where you're going, but I don't think that would make sense here. In the original dataframe, each row is an individual, with several readings at different times (not shown). It will be straightforward to see how those readings progress, or whether they meet certain medical criteria if they are in separate columns. The individual is the unit of analysis and it makes most sense to have all their readings in the same row.